# Getting Messages from child Windows

Tags: mfc

I want to getting messages from child window. I am not able to do. Pls help me out.
I want a retrieve a message send by another child window.
Here user defined message is constant 510, and I am handling this inside OnGirish()

// WndSecond.cpp : implementation file
    //

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DemoB.h"
#include "WndSecond.h"

// #define ID_GIRISH 500
// CWndSecond

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CWndSecond, CWnd)
//Constructor
CWndSecond::CWndSecond()
{

}
//Destructor
CWndSecond::~CWndSecond()
{
}

//Message map for this window
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CWndSecond, CWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_COMMAND(510,OnGirish)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// CWndSecond message handlers


BOOL CWndSecond::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs) 
{
    if (!CWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs))
        return FALSE;

    cs.dwExStyle |= WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
    cs.lpszClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW|CS_DBLCLKS, 
        ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,255,0)), NULL);

    return TRUE;
}

void CWndSecond::OnPaint()
{
    CClientDC dc(this);
}

//Handler for retrieving user defined message sent by another window
void CWndSecond::OnGirish()
{
    //Here I want to retrieve the message sent by another child window
    GetMessae(510,0,0);
    MessageBox(_T("Message"), _T("Hello World"),MB_ICONASTERISK|MB_OK); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegisterWindowMessage is only required if you need to send inter-process messages, otherwise a constant of a value higher than WM_USER/WM_APP is fine. In an MFC application UI thread it's "never" right to call GetMessage() directly. The MFC framework handles the message queue itself and dispatches the messages to your windows. To send a message to a specific window use ::SendMessage or ::PostMessage as appropriate with the receivers window handle as the first argument, and use ON_MESSAGE in your message map. Prototype for handler `LRESULT func(WPARAM,LPARAM);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [RegisterWindowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to define the message. And, the ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE macro to handle it.

Comment: @rrirower- thanks a lot for help me out..I hope you'll help me out again in future.

Comment: We can Use ON_MESSAGE handler for defining user defined message and handle by using function afx_msg LRESULT Function_name(WPARAM,LPARAM); WPARAM and LPARAM will be user defined.

Comment: -1 `RegisterWindowMessage` is the wrong tool. If you control both the code sending and receiving a message, use a statically defined message identifier in the `WM_APP+x` range. If you are the implementer of the receiving window's window class, use a message in the `WM_USER+x` range.